# Program "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

Tags: c++, xcode

I have a function that reverses a char array, but when it gets to a certain point, I receive the error. Can anyone help? I have looked, but have not found anything specific geared towards this, I think.

```
char* strrev( char* s )
{
    char  c;
    char* s0 = s - 1;
    char* s1 = s;

    /* Find the end of the string */
    while (*s1) ++s1;

    /* Reverse it */
    while (s1-- > ++s0)
    {
        c   = *s0;
        *s0 = *s1;    // This is where I am receiving the Bad Access.
        *s1 =  c;
    }

    return s;
}
```

Comment: Could you be passing a non-NULL-terminated string to your function? I would expect you to get the error in the first while loop, but maybe some kind of optimization is making it so that the access doesn't actually happen until the second loop.

Comment: in this line `char* s0 = s - 1;` where do you expect s0 to point to? This line is responsible for the flaw in the code. Just make s0 = s1 and write the code accordingly and you will be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

I'll wager a guess that you're calling your function like this:

```
char *s = strrev("pancakes");
```

If so, then you're trying to modify a string literal and many systems put string literals in read-only memory. If you do it like this:

```
char s1[] = "pancakes";
char *s2  = strrev(s1);
```

you should have better luck.

Comment: If it's being called that way the compiler should be issuing at least a warning about converting const char* to char*. If the compiler has better defaults or is passed suitable options then it would issue an error instead.

Comment: I'm just calling the function like this:   strrev(code);   And I am not receiving any warnings or errors ahead of time.

Comment: @bames53: True, the compiler complain about dropping the const. You'd hope that everyone cranked up their warning flags and added `-Werror` but not everyone is properly strict and paranoid. I don't see anything else that would cause it to break right there but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: code comes from a long program that if you saw, you would go like "AHHHH". Actually, not too long. "code" is a char *code;

Comment: @user1046825: Perhaps the memory error is actually elsewhere but you're only seeing it in `strrev`. Have you tried valgrind?

Comment: No, I am still new at everything. Can you explain?

Comment: @user1046825: Valgrind is a memory access checking tool (among other things): http://valgrind.org/